# ConcurrentModificationException in multithreaded Java application

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, server, concurrentmodification

I have the following problem: We are doing multithreaded game and there is a `Server` which extends `Thread` and is the host of the game, as well there is a `GameUpdater` which also extends `Thread` and is a prototype of game engine. The problem is that `GameUpdater` adds and removes some object to the game, while `Server` sends to `Client` all updates (example given below):

```
private void sendUpdatedAsteroids() {
        Collection<Asteroid> asteroids = this.game.getAsteroids();
        StringBuilder existentAsteroids = new StringBuilder();
        for(Asteroid asteroid : asteroids) {
            if (!asteroid.isDestroyed()) {
                existentAsteroids.append(asteroid.getUniqueID());
                existentAsteroids.append("@");

                Message message = new Message();
                message.encryptObject(asteroid);
                try {
                    this.sendMessage(message);
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }


        Message message = new Message(MessageType.GENERAL, existentAsteroids.toString());
        try {
            sendMessage(message);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The following error always occurs:

```
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1042)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:996)
```

I think that the problem is that `GameUpdater` removes and adds objects, and then `Server` tries to send to `Client` non-existing objects. The solution to the problem was found: making copy of asteroids and then send it to `Client`, but the problem is that it takes a lot of memory. Any other solutions are appreciated (for example make two different threads working together).

Comment: This code does not have anything that could result jn the exception. The exception will occur if iteration and add/remove operation happening at the same time. Kindly check the code where above operation might be happening n if possible add the code to the question

Comment: That's why I wrote that the problem is that two separate threads modify this ArrayList and it results in this exception.

Comment: If you know which method is modifying the list just make them syncronized using synchronized  keyword. It depends on at what level you wish to block the threads i.e at method level or some block of code

Comment: Use Vector (in order to synchronize the list of Asteroids)instead of ArrayList

Comment: What do you mean, you send updated astroids? You're looping over all of the astroids and sending them.

Comment: Thank you for syncronized, it seems to work now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If element updates in list (add/remove) is less frequent compare to Iteration, I would suggest to consider CopyOnWriteArrayList.
Unless frequent write is involved, It is efficient for safe iteration.

Otherwise Collections.SynchronizedList could be used with synchronized block over iteration of the list. This will cause the other thread to wait till iteration completes